# Margin on Floating DIVs

Tags: css, html

How do you apply margin on floating elements? I'm trying to center this 3 boxes and add spaces between them.

```
<div id="background">
    <div class="box">
    1
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    2
    </div>
    <div class="box">
    3
    <div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#background
{
width:530px;
height:160px;
background-color:gray;   
overflow:hide;
padding:5px;
}

.box
{
background-color:white;
width:160px;
height:150px;
float:left;
margin:auto;
border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

link on jsfiddle below.

```
[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/P63Sw/
```

Comment: Update your question before you get more downvotes.. Add relevant code. Adding link to fiddle even wont work.. Add code in your question

Comment: got it, sorry about that @Pilot.

Comment: take a look @ http://jsfiddle.net/P63Sw/3/

Comment: @Pilot thank you! that's exactly what i want to do, but one last thing how to I align the boxes vertically? it's already center on left and right, how about the top and bottom?

Comment: @Darren http://jsfiddle.net/P63Sw/4/

Comment: @Darren you can mark the ans correct.

Answer (score 0):

Bit changes in your css code,

```
#background {
    width:530px;
    display: table-cell;    <!--just to make it appear as a table-cell so than we can use vertical align and text-align on it-->
    vertical-align:middle;  <!--just to align in the middle vertically-->
    height:160px;
    background-color:gray;
    overflow:hide;
    padding:5px;
    text-align: center;     <!--will align it horizontally center-->
}
.box {
    background-color:white;
    width:160px;
    display: inline-block;
    height:150px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```